# Transferring the data printed by NG-repeat in one html to another html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, service

ok, so i started getting the hang of ng-repeat and how to use it. but now i have a table which is rendered by ng-repeat in one html page and i have to print the same table on another html page.

```html
<tr ng-class-odd="b" ng-class-even="" ng-repeat="result in teamResults">
                                        <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
                                        <td>{{result.lastName}}</td>
                                        <td>{{result.teamName}}</td>
                                        <td>{{result.location}}</td>
  </tr>
```

teamResults is an array in my controller which gets data from a ajax call. i want to print the same table on another html page when a link is clicked. what i observed when i linked the controller to the new html page is that the controller is re instantied and the array is empty. how can i transfer the data from the first html page to the second page without having to make another service call in the second html page ?? im a noob in angular and any in sight  into this would be helpful . thank in advance for all the answer and sorry again if this a noob question

UPDATE :  when i click a link a new html page opens up and i need to print the same data on that page.but the data disappears. I even used a service to store the data but i cant seem to pass it to the controller linked to the new HTML page

Comment: You can have a on click method call with  passing  the value through the parameter to controller which you are about to call.And assign the value to the scope variable and use it in your another html .

Answer (score 0):

Consider this as an Sample example model :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app>
    <table ng-controller="MyController">
          <tr ng-class-odd="b" ng-class-even="" ng-repeat="result in teamResults">
                                        <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
                                        <td>{{result.lastName}}</td>
                                        <td>{{result.teamName}}</td>
                                        <td>{{result.location}}</td>
          <button ng-click="getRowData(result)">view</button>
            </tr>
        </div>
    </table>
    <script>
        function MyController($scope, $http) {

            $scope.getRowData = function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try defining teamResults in $rootScope

```
$rootScope.teamResults=yourdata;
```

Comment: the thing is that when i click a link a new html page opens up and i need to print the same data on that page.but the data disappears. I even used a service to store the data but i cant seem to pass it to the controller linked to the new HTML page

Comment: is it safe using the $rootscope ??? i read that , it might make the state of the program unstable, im not sure.

Comment: Occasionally there are pieces of data that you want to make global to the whole app. For these, you can inject $rootScope and set values on it like any other scope. Since the scopes inherit from the root scope, these values will be available to the expressions attached to directives like ng-show just like values on your local $scope.